# Get DISTINCT COUNT in one pass in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a table like below:

```
Region    Country    Manufacturer    Brand    Period    Spend
R1        C1         M1              B1       2016      5
R1        C1         M1              B1       2017      10
R1        C1         M1              B1       2017      20
R1        C1         M1              B2       2016      15
R1        C1         M1              B3       2017      20
R1        C2         M1              B1       2017      5
R1        C2         M2              B4       2017      25
R1        C2         M2              B5       2017      30
R2        C3         M1              B1       2017      35
R2        C3         M2              B4       2017      40
R2        C3         M2              B5       2017      45
...
```

I wrote the query below to aggregate them:

```
SELECT [Region]
    ,[Country]
    ,[Manufacturer]
    ,[Brand]
    ,Period
    ,SUM([Spend]) AS [Spend]
FROM myTable
GROUP BY [Region]
    ,[Country]
    ,[Manufacturer]
    ,[Brand]
    ,[Period]
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4
```

which yields something like below:

```
Region    Country    Manufacturer    Brand    Period    Spend
R1        C1         M1              B1       2016      5
R1        C1         M1              B1       2017      30 -- this row is an aggregate from raw table above
R1        C1         M1              B2       2016      15
R1        C1         M1              B3       2017      20
R1        C2         M1              B1       2017      4  -- aggregated result
R1        C2         M2              B4       2017      25
R1        C2         M2              B5       2017      30
R2        C3         M2              B4       2017      40
R2        C3         M2              B5       2017      45
```

I'd like to add another column to the above table that shows the `DISTINCT COUNT` of `Brand` grouped by `Region`,`Country`,`Manufacturer` and `Period`. So the final table would become as follow:

```
Region    Country    Manufacturer    Brand    Period    Spend    UniqBrandCount
R1        C1         M1              B1       2016      5        2 -- two brands by R1, C1, M1 in 2016
R1        C1         M1              B1       2017      30       1
R1        C1         M1              B2       2016      15       2 -- same as first row's result
R1        C1         M1              B3       2017      20       1
R1        C2         M1              B1       2017      4        1
R1        C2         M2              B4       2017      25       2
R1        C2         M2              B5       2017      30       2
R2        C3         M2              B4       2017      40       2
R2        C3         M2              B5       2017      45       2
```

I know how to get to final result in three steps.

1. Run this query (Query #1):

   SELECT [Region]
       ,[Country]
       ,[Manufacturer]
       ,[Period]
       ,COUNT(DISTINCT [Brand]) AS [BrandCount]
   INTO Temp1
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY [Region]
       ,[Country]
       ,[Manufacturer]
       ,[Period]
2. Run this query (Query #2)

   SELECT [Region]
       ,[Country]
       ,[Manufacturer]
       ,[Brand]
       ,YEAR([Period]) AS Period
       ,SUM([Spend]) AS [Spend]
   INTO Temp2
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY [Region]
       ,[Country]
       ,[Manufacturer]
       ,[Brand]
       ,[Period]
3. Then `LEFT JOIN` `Temp2` and `Temp1` to bring in `[BrandCount]` from the latter like below:

   SELECT a.*
       ,b.*
   FROM Temp2 AS a
   LEFT JOIN Temp1 AS b ON a.[Region] = b.[Region]
       AND a.[Country] = b.[Country]
       AND a.[Advertiser] = b.[Advertiser]
       AND a.[Period] = b.[Period]

I'm pretty sure there is a more efficient way to do this, is there? Thank you in advance for your suggestions/answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing heavily from this question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89031/using-distinct-in-window-function-with-over

Count Distinct doesn't work, so dense_rank is required. Ranking the brands in forward and then reverse order, and then subtracting 1 gives the distinct count.

Your sum function can also be rewritten using `PARTITION BY` logic. This way you can use different grouping levels for each aggregation:

```
SELECT 
[Region]
,[Country]
,[Manufacturer]
,[Brand]
,[Period]
,dense_rank() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY 
     [Region] 
    ,[Country]
    ,[Manufacturer]
    ,[Period] Order by Brand) 
+ dense_rank() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY 
     [Region] 
    ,[Country]
    ,[Manufacturer]
    ,[Period] Order by Brand Desc) 
- 1  
AS [BrandCount]
,SUM([Spend]) OVER
    (PARTITION BY
     [Region] 
    ,[Country]
    ,[Manufacturer]
    ,[Brand]
    ,[Period]) as [Spend]
from
myTable
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4
```

You may then need to reduce the number of rows in your output, as this syntax gives the same number of rows as myTable, but with the aggregation totals appearing on each row they apply to:

```
R1  C1  M1  B1  2016    2   5
R1  C1  M1  B1  2017    2   30 --dup1
R1  C1  M1  B1  2017    2   30 --dup1
R1  C1  M1  B2  2016    2   15
R1  C1  M1  B3  2017    2   20
R1  C2  M1  B1  2017    1   5
R1  C2  M2  B4  2017    2   25
R1  C2  M2  B5  2017    2   30
R2  C3  M1  B1  2017    1   35
R2  C3  M2  B4  2017    2   40
R2  C3  M2  B5  2017    2   45
```

Selecting distinct rows from this output gives you what you need.

#### How the dense_rank trick works

Consider this data:

```
Col1    Col2
B       1
B       1
B       3
B       5
B       7
B       9
```

dense_rank() ranks data according to the number of distinct items before the current one, plus 1. So:

> 1->1, 3->2, 5->3, 7->4, 9->5.

In reverse order (using `desc`) this yields the reverse pattern:

> 1->5, 3->4, 5->3, 7->2, 9->1:

Adding these ranks together gives the same value:

> 1+5 = 2+4 = 3+3 = 4+2 = 5+1 = 6

The wording is helpful here,

```
(number of distinct items before + 1) + (number of distinct items after + 1) 
= number of distinct OTHER items before AND after + 2 
= Total number of distinct items + 1
```

So to get the total number of distinct items, add the `ascending` and `descending` dense_ranks together and subtract 1.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer! It's a bit mind twisting to see immediately why `DESNSE_RANK` forward and reverse - 1 would come out to be the same as `DISTINCT COUNT` of Brand. If there's any resource that explains why it works, could you please share? I will verify the result and choose your reply as the answer (because it's the most comprehensive). I will also try to write up as a comment here what I learn about why `DENSE_RANK` trick works after thinking over it tonight. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you so much for a very clear explanation!! Now it makes sense to me why `DENSE_RANK` should work. Although Martin's answer below is also nice (and doesn't not require deduping the rows afterward), I'll accept this one. For those looking for answers, please look at Martin's answer below as well. Thank you so much, @mjsqu!

Comment: No problem, I didn't understand it at first, so I had to create a worked example to work out why!

Answer (score 2):

The tag to your question;

> window-functions

suggests you have a pretty good idea.

For **DISTINCT COUNT of Brand grouped by Region,Country,Manufacturer and Period**: you may write:

```
Select   Region 
        ,Country
        ,Manufacturer
        ,Brand
        ,Period
        ,Spend
        ,DENSE_RANK() Over (Partition By Region, Country, Manufacturer, Period Order By Brand asc) 
         + DENSE_RANK() Over (Partition By Region, Country, Manufacturer, Period Order By Brand desc) 
         -1 UniqBrandCount
From myTable T1
Order By 1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 1):

The double `dense_rank` idea means that you need two sorts (assuming no index exists that provides sort order). Assuming no `NULL` brands (as that idea does) you can use a single `dense_rank` and a windowed `MAX` as below ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3ff21754a25fa50991e023ccb4d2b7a4))

```
WITH T1
     AS (SELECT *,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Region], [Country], [Manufacturer], [Period] ORDER BY Brand) AS [dr]
         FROM   myTable),
     T2
     AS (SELECT *,
                MAX([dr]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Region], [Country], [Manufacturer], [Period]) AS UniqBrandCount
         FROM   T1)
SELECT [Region],
       [Country],
       [Manufacturer],
       [Brand],
       Period,
       SUM([Spend])        AS [Spend],
       MAX(UniqBrandCount) AS UniqBrandCount
FROM   T2
GROUP  BY [Region],
          [Country],
          [Manufacturer],
          [Brand],
          [Period]
ORDER  BY [Region],
          [Country],
          [Manufacturer],
          [Period],
          Brand
```

The above has some inevitable spooling (it isn't possible to do this in a 100% streaming manner) but a single sort.

Strangely the final order by clause is needed to keep the number of sorts down to one (or zero if a suitable index exists).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing an alternative (and presumably more efficient) approach! Based on your explanation, I interpret that using `DENSE_RANK` incurs one sort, but `MAX` does not (I mean, I can see that in the query analyzer output, but just wondering how, without sorting, `MAX` values were found)? I'm still a newbie in learning SQL, so maybe one day, I'll be able to understand the inner workings better. :) One more question, spooling is because the `MAX` part has to wait for the `DENSE_RANK` part to finish? Thank you so much!

Comment: @user1330974 - From Right to Left the rows are read from the table and sorted into order of `[Region], [Country], [Manufacturer], [Period], Brand`. The next two segment and sequence project operators calculate the dense_rank.  The rows with this calculated  dense_rank value are read into a spool. As soon as a new `[Region], [Country], [Manufacturer], [Period]` group is reached then the rows in the spool for the previous group have the MAX calculated on them and then the rows from the spool are replayed with this MAX value added to them.

Comment: More about dense_rank http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/07/28/the-segment-and-sequence-project-iterators.aspx and windowed aggregates http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/07/28/partitioning-and-the-common-subexpression-spool.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation of how to read the query plan as well as sharing a really good resource/blog to read more about the window functions! Because of your explanation, the query plan now makes partial sense to me and I can confirm that your suggested solution works and takes just about 6-8 secs! Side note: I accepted the other solution above because it came in a bit earlier than yours and it also worked. Hope you would understand. :)